# One Click Publish dotnet tool install dotnet-ef error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0, one-click-web-publishing

When I edit my .pubxml file in the one click publish screen. My Entity-Framework Migrations section shows this error and I can't find any solutions that work for me. Has anyone had this issue or know how to resolve it?

I ran `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --ignore-failed-sources`

and got the message `Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.`

[image]

Comment: I am getting same error could you please help , how you resloved it

Comment: I believe it was a nuget feed issue. For some reason the authorization was not working appropriately and I readded the problem nuget feed and everything seemed to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following correct Stack Overflow etiquette here, but: in my case, it turned out that this error was a red herring. The problem was in my appsettings.json file; where a connection string had been created for my local database (which I don't use).

If you expand the "Databases" section in the Publish settings, and see a similar reference to an unused local database, then stripping out the connection string should hopefully lead to the entire "Entity Framework Migrations" section disappearing (and the error, with it).

(Of course, if you actually use EF migrations, then this solution may not work for you...)